# Перенос строки при чтении файла

Tags: php, html, html5

Есть форма которая отправляется из `<textarea>` в обработчик, он ее записывает в файл, далее обработчик №2 читает этот файл (текст) и выводит его на html странице. Вопрос таков: 
Как сделать так чтобы оператор php `echo` читал содержимое файла 
и выводил его на html страницу вместе с переносом строк , т.к
В файле записано:

```
Hello
World
```

но php выводит его на html страницу как

```
Hello World
```

Пробовал ставить в начале html документа тэг `<pre>`, но из-за него бывает текст то ли сползает, то ли становится кривым, есть ли какой другой способ, может средствами самого php? либо какие-то другие тэги в html.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: PHP выводит так, как записано, в чём вы можете убедиться, открыв исходники html-страницы. Просто стандартное поведение вывода текста на html-страницах - преобразовывать любые идущие подряд пробельные символы в один простой пробел.

Comment: да я так и понял , но есть html тэг который отменит это преобразование помимо <pre> ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте в обработчике воспользоваться функцией `nl2br()`

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не совсем по PHP, т.к. данные вы прочитали правильно.

Попробуйте поиграться с CSS свойством [white-space](http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space).

См. вложенный пример.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
Hello
World
Hello mega mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega  mega World!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вопрос решается и средствами php , как подсказали выше , проблему решила функция nl2br()

Comment: Здесь дело вкуса - менять данные на сервере или вывести их в нужном виде на клиенте.